# How to put the last score between two diffrent google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two google spreadsheets. Both of them has a column which contains the scores.
I would like to create a new column which has the last score (in each row) between the first and second google spreadsheet.

Comment: could this help? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en especially the last sentence about importrange. Also: let us know how you did it when done.

Comment: @Chris with importrange function doesn't work because I have two different sheets.

Comment: @pnuts my question is very clear

Comment: @user172238 sure it won't work? it says you can tell it an URL for a spreadsheet: IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10") so it certainly looks like it should do the trick.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for your answer, but it didn't work